# EVR equivalent to IVMRMonitorConfig or IVMRMonitorConfig9?

Tags: directshow

Using `VMR7` and `VMR9`, I can query interface from renderer for `IVMRMonitorConfig[9]` to ask monitor related informations via [IVMRMonitorConfig::GetAvailableMonitors()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390488(v=vs.85).aspx). My purpose is to check the what underlying VGA of renderer by checking the keyword in `VMRMONITORINFO[9]::szDescription`. ex: nvidia.

For [EVR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375607(v=vs.85).aspx), everything is new and different. I try to find the interface providing monitor related or something with hardware information. Here is what I've looked up but not wanted.

- `IEVRFilterConfig` provides static configuration
- `IMFVideoRenderer` provides service that reset new presenter
- `IMFVideoDeviceID`(RENDER_SERVICE) provides Device GUID. But it looks like  generally gives `IID_IDirect3DDevice9` as return.
- `IMFVideoDisplayControl` provides output window control and query

Comment: Use [Multi-monitor API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145072) to map monitor desktop area to specific coordinates. Move hosting window and child coordinates using `IMFVideoDisplayControl` respectively.